# Longest path on a grid

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

For any $z \times y$ grid graph with $z$ rows consisting of $y$ vertices, find the path with the greatest length in such a graph. A path is considered where no vertices and no edges are repeated. Give some explanation as to why this is the longest path.

Let  $z, y \ge 2$

What I have so far:

If we have a grid of $z \times y$ then there are $2zy - z -y$ edges in the grid total. I think it's safe to assume that there are no paths containing all edges. Now how can I determine the upper bound of the longest path and then prove there exists some path having this length?

Comment: Think about how the number of vertices restricts the length.

Comment: My first try, which might not succeed, would be to consider grid points, rather than edges.  If there are $~A~$ grid points, and a path is possible that hits each grid points, then the traversed distance will be $~2A - 2,~$ which is clearly the longest path.  If either dimension is an even number, then it is clearly possible to traverse all grid points, where no grid point is *re-visited*.  So, the problem reduces to consideration of a grid where both dimensions are odd.

Comment: Re last comment, contrast the *optimal path* in a $~3 \times 2~$ grid with the optimal path in a $~3 \times 3~$ grid.

Comment: Consider zigzag paths ("mainly horizontal" or "mainly vertical") but also spiral paths...

Comment: @user2661923 Isn't the traversed distance $A-1$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Good catch, my blindness.  I was counting grid-point entrances and exits, overlooking that each 1 unit distance exits one grid point and enters another grid point.

Comment: @user2661923 so you're saying that for odd grids this does not hold up? Also how could I convert that formula into edges?

Comment: @andydandy No, it also holds up for odd grids.  It simply requires a little more thought.  Also, assume that there are $~A~$ grid points, and you start at one grid point, finish at another, and along the way visit every other grid point.  Then the number of grid point [exits + entrances] is $~2A - 2.~$ Further, each traversal of one edge (i.e. 1 unit) involves one grid point exit and one grid point entrance.  So, the total distance traversed is $~\dfrac{2A-2}{2}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Why talk about "exits + entrances"? That seems to unnecessarily complicate this. If we connect all $A$ vertices as a path, then the length is $A-1$.  $\quad$ The unknown is if this is doable for oddXodd, which it actually is.

Comment: @CalvinLin Why do you subtract 1 from A?

Comment: @CalvinLin Only because that was the way that I thought about the problem.  I focused on how many grid points there were, and that you had to enter and leave all of them but $~2.$

Comment: @andydandy Because if (for example) there are only two grid points, you are only traveling 1 unit.  Thereafter, each grid point added represents an additional edge to be traveled.